# Save Site as Template: Why is the "include content" section available for some sites but not others?

Tags: site-template, wiki

For some of our SharePoint sites and sub-sites, the "include content" checkbox is not available on the Save Site as Template page (in particular, Wiki sites).  By "not available" I mean that the "include content" section is not visible, not just greyed out.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a list of what is included and what is not included when saving site as template:

- [Save a SharePoint site as a template](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/save-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template-HA101782501.aspx#_Toc258332696)

> **NOT INCLUDED IN USER SOLUTION WSP**
>
> Publishing pages and publishing sites

And Enterprise Wiki is publishing template:

- [Sites and site collections overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262410.aspx#section3)

> **Template**       Enterprise Wiki
>
> **Purpose**           A site on which you can publish knowledge that
>   you capture and want to share across the enterprise. It provides an
>   easy content editing experience in a single location for co-authoring
>   content, for discussions, and for managing projects.
>
> **Category in Site Collection**   Publishing
>
> **Category in Site**   Content